Why are editor.js tools not showing up in my code?
I am using editor.js to add a text editor to my program. Editor.js is installed and working, but the tools do not. I only have the functionality to create paragraphs.
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs'; 
import Header from '@editorjs/header'; 
import List from '@editorjs/list'; 

const editor = new EditorJS({ 
  /** 
   * Id of Element that should contain the Editor 
   */ 
  holder: 'editorjs', 

  /** 
   * Available Tools list. 
   * Pass Tool's class or Settings object for each Tool you want to use 
   */ 
  tools: { 
    header: {
      class: Header, 
      inlineToolbar: ['link'] 
    }, 
    list: { 
      class: List, 
      inlineToolbar: true 
    } 
  }, 
})
        },
      },
    },
  });
  }, 
})


There is something odd with the code you posted. It has a lot more closing brakets than opening ones. I dont know if it was wrongly copied, otherwise It might be the cause of some issues.

Sorry - I had more tools added before posting this and didn't remove the brackets. Even with them removed, I still am not seeing the list/header tools in my browser.

add at least one  inlineToolbar for eg : ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']
const editor = new EditorJS({
    holder: 'editorjs',
    inlineToolbar:['bold', 'italic', 'underline'] ,
    tools: {
        header: {
            class: Header,
            inlineToolbar: true
        },
        list: {
            class: List,
            inlineToolbar: true
        }
    },
})

